# Datetime Time Zone Scraping Python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I am trying to scrape and sort articles with a body, headline, and date column. However, when pulling the date, I’m running into an error with the time zone:

```
ValueError: time data 'Jun 1, 2022 2:49PM EDT' does not match format '%b %d, %Y %H:%M%p %z'
```

My code is as follows:

```
def get_info(url):
    headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    news = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'body__content'}).text
    headline = soup.find('h1').text
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(soup.find('time').text, "%b %d, %Y %H:%M%p %z")
    columns = [news, headline, date]
    column_names = ['News','Headline','Date']
    return dict(zip(column_names, columns))
```

Is there a way to grab the time zone in a similar method or just drop it overall?

Comment: Seems that the issue is in %z. %z is in the form ±HHMM, and %Z recognises only GMT and UTC

Comment: You'll *always* have a problem with what you're attempting to do, because time zone abbreviations are not unique or consistent.  Consider that "CST" could mean Central Standard Time, Cuba Standard Time, or China Standard Time.  "IST" could mean India Standard Time, Israel Standard Time, or Ireland Summer Time.  Hawaiian time could be abbreviated HST or HAST.  And there are many more examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note %z in strptime() is for timezone offsets not names and %Z only accepts certain values for time zones. For details see [API docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Simplest option is to use [dateparser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) module to parse dates with time zone names (e.g. EDT).

```python
import dateparser

s = "Jun 1, 2022 2:49PM EDT"
d =  dateparser.parse(s)
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
2022-06-01 14:49:00-04:00
```

Many of the date modules (e.g. [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/)) have timezone offsets defined for "EST", "PST", etc. but "EDT" is less common. These modules would need you to define the timezone with the offset as UTC-04:00.

```python
import dateutil.parser

s = "Jun 1, 2022 2:49PM EDT"
tzinfos = {"EDT": -14400}
d = dateutil.parser.parse(s, tzinfos=tzinfos)
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
2022-06-01 14:49:00-04:00
```

Comment: Note that dateutil parser accepts a kwarg `tzinfos`, which allows you to supply a mapping dict, mapping tz abbreviations (like "EDT") to specific IANA-database time zones (e.g. America/New_York).

Answer (score 0):

As alternate to @CodeMonkey solution, you may also try it by pandas :

```
pd.to_datetime('Jun 1, 2022 2:49PM EDT').tz_localize('US/Eastern')
```